# When applying for a tourist visa for Australia as a South African, do I need to supply bank statements?

Tags: visas, australia, south-african-citizens, proof-provenance-of-funds

How many bank statements are required when applying for a travel visa to Australia? I'm a South African citizen.

Comment: Where are you from and what type of visa is it??

Comment: South Africa , applying for travel/tourist visa?

Comment: Read this https://www.homeaffairs.gov.au/trav/visa-1/600-/Visitor-visa-(subclass-600)-Tourist-Stream-document-checklist the usual bank statement requirement is 3 or 6 months. not sure about australia

Answer (score 1):

VFS Global, through which you apply for a visitor visa for Australia, has varying instructions for bankbook or bank statements. Depending on country of application, they range from 3 to 6 months.

However, the VFS Global instructions for South African applicants directs you to the [Department of Home Affairs](https://www.homeaffairs.gov.au/trav/visa-1/600-/Visitor-visa-(subclass-600)-Tourist-Stream-document-checklist) checklist which simply states:

> Evidence of sufficient funds, such as personal bank statements, pay slips, audited accounts or credit card limit

If you're at all uncertain, bank statements for the last 3 months should suffice, particularly if you do not have other evidence (e.g., pay slips or credit card predetermined limit).